# Why are models often described as systems of ODE's rather than just the functions themselves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

> > Take for instance the following model describing an epedemic accounting for the number of susceptible people $S$ and the number of infected people $I$
> >     $$\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = -aS(t) \cdot I(t)$$
> >     $$\frac{dI(t)}{dt}=aS(t) \cdot I(t) - bI(t)$$, where $a,b>0$

What are the reasons that models like this are very often described by ODE's rather than just describing them as regular functions, i.e look at the development of $S(t)$ and $I(t)$? \

After all, aren't we interested in knowing about the number of people in the different states? Using ODE's just seems to complicate matters.

Comment: Because experiments and physics often tell us only the instantaneous velocity vector (more generally, the vector of instantaneous change of state) at each time instant, not the state of the system itself.

Comment: Because it is often easier to describe the constraints than the actual behaviours themselves. The ODE describes local behaviour, the solutions are global in nature. Solving local problems is easier than solving global problems :-).

Comment: Many of the "laws" that govern physical and biological processes are described in terms of integral or differential equations. Conservation laws are a great example in physics. For epidemic models, the number of new infections created by a single infected person is very important, and that is a rate, hence derivatives are a very natural way to specify the system.

Comment: This is like asking “why do we have to solve problems at all rather than just work with the answers?” The whole point is that you don’t know the functions in advance. You model the unknown functions by things you do know, thanks to data and theory: how they evolve over time or how they depend on other variables, etc.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - I guess you could work the the ordinary functions, learn from the data and then create a model? Is that like working with the answers?

Comment: But you don't know the answers. Experimentation is difficult or impossible (we really don't want an experimental smallpox epidemic), and only gives you one set of initial conditions at a time.